# What can I do to prevent big holes in the bottom of bread loaves?

Tags: bread

Can you give me any ideas to control this type of hole in bread?

[image: this is a long loaf bread containing big holes in the bottom side]

Comment: Can you by any chance link to your recipe or describe it? It's possible to tell a lot from pictures but details help!

Comment: Were the seams intentional?  The loaves looked like they were shaped with too much bench flour on them.  That could be the reason for the holes as well.

Comment: Seems like a sure case of, dry dough, to me...

Comment: Is the bread filled, or simply twisted/braided?

Comment: How did you shape the dough before you put it in the pan, and did it have a final proof in the pan before baking?  It looks like the bread had a bit of a twist to it, but wasn't given a chance to relax before baking.  (although the nature of the twisting might still trap a bubble of air under the bread)

Answer (score 3):

When I had a similar result many years ago, I finally figured out that the problem was a combination of how I shaped the loaves and letting them *over* rise in the pan.  It also looks to me that these loaves were twisted when formed.  If so, perhaps try a different method of shaping them such as a braid, for a similar look.  Moreover, check your recipe for how much the dough should rise in the pan before going into the oven.  Some call for rising to the level of the bread pan, some call for an inch (rarely more) above the edge of the pan.  Finally, make sure your oven is fully preheated, especially if using a baking stone.